# How pricing is being calculated for used laptops on different websites?

Tags: api, calculator, price

I am trying to build something similar of cashinyourgadgets.co.uk or buymylaptop.co.uk and for now I give pricing to customers manually i.e first they fill the form and then I get an email and then I reply back with a price.

I also want to automate the pricing like its on the above mentioned websites and they all seems to be using some similar code to calculate the pricing because they all give almost same price back.

Are they using some API ? Does anyone know and can point me in the right direction ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I was faced with a similar issue, I would create an api on those websites. Each time I need to calculate the price for a product,  the api fetches the price from those websites, compares them and returns a new price based on that.

Comment: But that's the lazy way, how do you think they're doing it or maybe what type of logic they're using ?